# Maya Python, Connect to 2 lists

Tags: python, rendering, maya

So guys, this is question about Maya, python.

Can I create a loop and set shader A color to R shader B color to G and shaderC to B

```
for i in range(5):
    shader = cmds.shadingNode ('surfaceShader', name=('mm'+str(i)), asShader=True)
    cmds.sets(renderable=True, noSurfaceShader=True, empty=True, name=('mmSG'+str(i)))
    cmds.setAttr(shader +'.outColor', 1,0,0)
```

this is what I have so far, I am stucking in every 3 steps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there - you just need to connect the shader's `outColor` to the `surfaceShader` attribute on the shading group:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

for i in range(5):
    shader = cmds.shadingNode ('surfaceShader', name=('mm'+str(i)), asShader=True)
    sg = cmds.sets(renderable=True, noSurfaceShader=True, empty=True, name=('mmSG'+str(i)))
    cmds.setAttr(shader +'.outColor', 1,0,0)
    cmds.connectAttr(shader + ".outColor", sg + ".surfaceShader")
```

## edit

I misread OP's intention. If the idea is to make a set of shaders with specified colors, you'd want to do something like this:

```
  colors = {'red': (1,0,0), 'blue': (0,1,0), 'green':(0,0,1)} 

  for name, color in colors.items():
      shader = cmds.shadingNode ('surfaceShader', name=(name), asShader=True)
      sg = cmds.sets(renderable=True, noSurfaceShader=True, empty=True, name=(name + "SG")
      cmds.setAttr(shader +'.outColor', color[0], color[1], color[2])
      cmds.connectAttr(shader + ".outColor", sg + ".surfaceShader")
```

Comment: Thank you for replying :)))Yes,uhmm but my question is how do I set shader[0] is Red, shader[1] is Green, shader[2] is Blue and make it loop....every three steps...

Comment: so you create a dictionary for it and How do you loop ir every three times? I mean..what if I have shader 4 5 6 7 8 9 10a

Comment: In this case it's only making 3 shaders called red, green and blue -- you didn't make it clear that you needed an open ended list. You can change the dictionary keys to 0, 1, and 2  then use a for loop with the % operator to get 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2.... out of any number of iterations

Comment: sorry was not being clear...I will give it a try with % operator...lol which I haven't tried that before 0 . 0

Answer (score 1):

So I end up using

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

shaderlist=[]

for i in range(5):
    shader = cmds.shadingNode ('surfaceShader', name=('mm'+str(i)), asShader=True)
    sg = cmds.sets(renderable=True, noSurfaceShader=True, empty=True, name=('mmSG'+str(i)))
    cmds.connectAttr(shader + ".outColor", sg + ".surfaceShader")
    shaderlist.append(shader)



for shader in shaderlist[0::3]:
    cmds.setAttr(shader+'.outColor', 1.0,0,0)

for shader in shaderlist[1::3]:
    cmds.setAttr(shader+'.outColor', 0,1,0)

for shader in shaderlist[2::3]:
    cmds.setAttr(shader+'.outColor', 0,0,1)
```